# NSURLSessionDataTask: func receives but returns no data

Tags: xcode, swift, nsurlsession

I've tried to create a simple function which receives URL and simply returns the HTML of the webpage. the `NSURLSessionDataTask` itself seems to work, I can see the whole html when I `println(data)`. But the `func` only returns the initial value "#!?". I suspect that the `DataTask` works  asynchronous? 
How can I handle this?

```
    func loadHTML(targetURL: String) -> String {

    var theTargetURL = NSURL(string:targetURL)
    var theResult = "#!?"

    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:theTargetURL)
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding))

        if error != nil {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
            theResult = "error"
        }
        if data != nil {
            theResult = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
            println("RECEIVED\t\t\(countElements(theResult)) CHARS")
        }
    });
    task.resume()

    return theResult
}
```

Comment: Have you done any asynchronous programming before ? This is asynchronous model but the function returns immediately, returning the immediate value. But the request takes a while to load and get the content from the url. It is better if you use completion block in your function, such that that is called when the request finishes.

Comment: I understood why it has to be asynchronous, but I'm not able to get a working completion block. I can't waive the `return` at the end of the `func`, at the same time a `return theResult` inside `if data != nil {}` results in an 'String can not converted to Void'-error. Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you would do it using a completion handler.

```
 typealias CompletionBlock = (NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> Void

  func loadHtml(targetUrlString: String, completion: CompletionBlock){

    let targetUrl = NSURL(string: targetUrlString)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: targetUrl)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: completion)
    task.resume()

  }
```

Then, call it from your method where it is needed,

```
func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()
  loadHtml("http://google.com", completion: { (responseData: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

    if responseData != nil{

      let resultString = NSString(data: responseData, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
      println(resultString)

      /* 
        do some task or update on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue){
          myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
      */

    }else if error != nil{

      println("Error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")

    }

  })
```